# What is at least weakly NP-hard problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, complexity-classes

It is known that some problem P is at least weakly NP-hard. What does **at least** part of the statement mean? Is it possible that problem P is strongly NP-hard? Is this a stronger, i.e. more precise, claim? Can we prove the problem is strongly NP-hard with polynomial time reduction?

Comment: Does [Wikipedia already answer your question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_NP-completeness)? In particular, it says "For example, bin packing is strongly NP-complete while the 0-1 Knapsack problem is only weakly NP-complete."

Comment: Maybe it does. What bothers me in this particular case is that we know that the problem IS AT LEAST weakly NP-hard. Does "AT LEAST" part indicate that problem may be harder?

Comment: The problem is weakly NP-hard, and might also be strongly NP-hard. Every strongly NP-hard problem is also weakly NP-hard.